# How to properly save and get data to/from MySql for most languages charset?

Tags: php

I've a Mysql Db and some tables. I'd like my App could store strings of multi world languages like: german, english, japanese, chinese.

My questions are:

- Is **utf8_unicode_ci** suitable to store strings in european lang, japanese, chinese etc ?
- What I have to do in PHP to store correctly strings in Mysql ? Is there some command to use before Insert/Update  data in my DB ?

Thanks

Comment: `utf8mb4` plus the collation of your choice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)